# hashing issue. How to use hazelcast map/multimap with byte arrays keys and values?

Tags: scala, hash, hazelcast

I'm trying to use hazelcast multimaps and maps with already-serialized data, i.e. with both keys and values being byte arrays. As demonstrated below, it does not work as expected.

In the javadoc it is noted in the "gotchas" section that the hashing is handled by hazelcast on the serialized form and does not rely on implementations of hashCode and equals (which are not overriden in case of byte arrays). So, I don't understand why apparently, Object.hashcode is used.

Could please somebody tell me how to use hazelcast maps with byte arrays?

Am I obliged to store byte array wrappers with adequately overridden hashcode/equal methods?

thanks for any help.

Problem:

```
 scala> val mm:MultiMap[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]] = hi.getMultiMap("test-baMuMa")
 mm: com.hazelcast.core.MultiMap[Array[Byte],Array[Byte]] = MultiMap [test-baMuMa]

 scala> mm.put("a".getBytes,"b".getBytes)
 res29: Boolean = true

 scala> mm.put("a".getBytes,"b".getBytes)
 res30: Boolean = true
 // => should return false..

 scala> mm.remove("a".getBytes,"b".getBytes)
 res31: Boolean = false
 // =>  should return true

 scala> mm.containsEntry("a".getBytes,"b".getBytes)
 res32: Boolean = false
 // =>  should return true (confirmed that removal did not occur)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer my own question here, because I think in the hazelcast documentation is not as clearly stated as it could be:

- key objets don't need to override equals/hashcode
- value objets need to override equals/hashcode

This can be seen by this simple test:

```
object TestHazel{

  class Klaus(a:Int) extends Serializable
  // class does not override equals/hashcode

  def main (args:Array[Byte]){
    import com.hazelcast.core._
    val hi = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance
    val map = hi.getMap[Klaus, Klaus]("asdf")
    val klaus1 = new Klaus(1)
    map.put(klaus1, klaus1)
    val containsKey = map.containsKey(new Klaus(1))
    println("\n\ncheck if key overrides equals/hashcode: " + containsKey)
    // true

    val containsValue = map.containsValue(new Klaus(1))
    println("\n\ncheck if value overrides equals/hashcode: " + containsValue + "\n\n")
    // false

    hi.shutdown
 }
}
```

So, in my case, for byte array values, a wrapper is required that overrides equals and hashcode. Unfortunately, value classes scala >= 2.10 cannot be used with classes overriding equals/hashcode, so we cannot avoid the boxing :-(

Furthermore, if you want to index with order, the wrapper has to be a comparable.

Here is a sensible implementation of such a wrapper:

```
class BAWrapper2(ba:Array[Byte], comparator:Comparator[Array[Byte]]) 
    extends Serializable with Comparable[BAWrapper2] 
{
  def data: Array[Byte] = if (ba == null) Array.empty[Byte] else ba
  def equals(other:BAWrapper2):Boolean = util.Arrays.equals(data, other.data)
  override def equals(obj:Any):Boolean = 
    if (obj.isInstanceOf[BAWrapper2]) equals(obj.asInstanceOf[BAWrapper2]) 
    else false
  override def compareTo(that:BAWrapper2):Int =
    if (comparator != null) comparator.compare(this.data, that.data)
    else BAComparator.compare(this.data, that.data)
  override def hashCode:Int = util.Arrays.hashCode(data)
}
```